# Liquibase - Handling Multiple Schemas on the SQL format

Tags: liquibase

The XML format changesets allow the property of `schemaName="mySchema"` to indicate which schema the DDL should be executed within for a given changeset - this can then be set using properties so that the same install could be deployed on servers which use different schema names. e.g.

```
<createTable tableName="test" schemaName="${primarySchema}">
```

Using the SQL format files for Liquibase there does not seem to be any documented equivalent to the schemaName property - nor any obvious mechanism to parameterized it beyond separating out all of the DDL per schema and running the migrate command once per set of schema files.

Is there a documented / undocumented way in which to give liquibase directives in the SQL file format to handle schemas in a neater fashion such as this? (which does not work)

```
--changeset me:1 schemaName:mySchema
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge: The class [`FormattedSqlChangeLogParser`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java) is used to read the configuration of formatted sql files. There is no option for the `schemaName` in it - but it should not be too hard to just add it and then set the schema. I have quickly checked Liquibase Jira for an improvement ticket to this but did not find any. Maybe you want to create one?

Comment: @Jens - I think you are on an 'answer' there opposed to a comment.

Comment: Well it's not really a solution...

Comment: Jira raised for the enhancement.

Comment: Add a link to the ticket. :-)

Comment: Hey everyone, any solutions to this?